Certbot Renew Challenge fails with 404 not found
My domain is: armenianpartners.com
I ran this command: sudo certbot renew
It produced this output:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/armenianpartners.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Running pre-hook command: service nginx stop
Error output from pre-hook command service:
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop nginx.service

Renewing an existing certificate for armenianpartners.com and 7 more domains
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for armenianpartners.com
http-01 challenge for backend.armenianpartners.com
http-01 challenge for social.armenianpartners.com
http-01 challenge for storage.armenianpartners.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain armenianpartners.com
Challenge failed for domain backend.armenianpartners.com
Challenge failed for domain social.armenianpartners.com
Challenge failed for domain storage.armenianpartners.com
http-01 challenge for armenianpartners.com
http-01 challenge for backend.armenianpartners.com
http-01 challenge for social.armenianpartners.com
http-01 challenge for storage.armenianpartners.com
Cleaning up challenges
Failed to renew certificate armenianpartners.com with error: Some challenges have failed.

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
All renewals failed. The following certificates could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/armenianpartners.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: armenianpartners.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: 34.240.171.41: Invalid response from
   https://armenianpartners.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/o9BoD4WZSb5pFCVoCgzlHhW-DXln3UcZYDrYHoXFV8M:
   404

   Domain: backend.armenianpartners.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: 34.240.171.41: Invalid response from
   https://backend.armenianpartners.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Osl7QCMc6NrrFVjBJt93hj8VKRW4qlHajBHgJN8MIpU:
   404

   Domain: social.armenianpartners.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: 34.240.171.41: Invalid response from
   https://social.armenianpartners.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/r8qBrqh516c-1lVuqERsytKB2rq-b5V1Qh5C3ERVQs8:
   403

   Domain: storage.armenianpartners.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: 34.240.171.41: Invalid response from
   https://storage.armenianpartners.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/DoWs_podJuoQCuDofmrWk20Vc0-ITxCT2JAdjjbi7R0:
   404

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.

My web server: Amazon linux
My hosting provider: AWS EC2
My nginx config:
#DEFINE MAX HASH
server_names_hash_bucket_size  256;


# HTTPS server

#TLS settings

ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/armenianpartners.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/armenianpartners.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

## FRONTEND ##
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # ssl on;

    root /var/app/current/frontend/web;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name armenianpartners.com armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;

    charset utf-8;

    # location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
    #    access_log off;
    #    expires max;
    # }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    client_max_body_size 32m;

    # There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile that can lead to
    # corrupted files, if not turned-off
    # sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        # fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;

        ## Cache
        # fastcgi_pass_header Cookie; # fill cookie valiables, $cookie_phpsessid for exmaple
        # fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie; # Use it with caution because it is cause SEO problems
        # fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$server_addr:$server_port$request_uri|$cookie_phpsessid"; # generating unique key
        # fastcgi_cache fastcgi_cache; # use fastcgi_cache keys_zone
        # fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=fastcgi_cache:16m max_size=256m inactive=1d;
        # fastcgi_temp_path  /tmp/nginx/temp 1 2; # temp files folder
        # fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500; # show cached page if error (even if it is outdated)
        # fastcgi_cache_valid 200 404 10s; # cache lifetime for 200 404;
        # or fastcgi_cache_valid any 10s; # use it if you want to cache any responses
    }

      location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html/frontend/web;
    }
}

## SOCIAL HUMHUB ##
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # ssl on;

    root /var/app/current/humhub;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name social.armenianpartners.com social.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;

    charset utf-8;

    # location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
    #    access_log off;
    #    expires max;
    # }

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html ;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views|\.|uploads/file) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets|static|themes|uploads) {
        expires 10d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }

    client_max_body_size 256m;

    # There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile that can lead to
    # corrupted files, if not turned-off
    # sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        #let yii catch the calls to unexisting PHP files
        set $fsn /index.php;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
                set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;

        ## Cache
        # fastcgi_pass_header Cookie; # fill cookie valiables, $cookie_phpsessid for exmaple
        # fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie; # Use it with caution because it is cause SEO problems
        # fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$server_addr:$server_port$request_uri|$cookie_phpsessid"; # generating unique key
        # fastcgi_cache fastcgi_cache; # use fastcgi_cache keys_zone
        # fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=fastcgi_cache:16m max_size=256m inactive=1d;
        # fastcgi_temp_path  /tmp/nginx/temp 1 2; # temp files folder
        # fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500; # show cached page if error (even if it is outdated)
        # fastcgi_cache_valid 200 404 10s; # cache lifetime for 200 404;
        # or fastcgi_cache_valid any 10s; # use it if you want to cache any responses
    }

       location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html/humhub;
    }
}

## BACKEND ##
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # ssl on;

    root /var/app/current/backend/web;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name backend.armenianpartners.com backend.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;

    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 16m;

    # There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile that can lead to
    # corrupted files, if not turned-off on Vagrant based setup
    # sendfile off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
    #     access_log off;
    #    expires max;
    # }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
   location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html/backend/web;
    }
}

## STORAGE ##
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # ssl on;

    root /var/app/current/storage/web;
    index index.html;

    server_name storage.armenianpartners.com storage.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;

    # expires max;

    # There is a VirtualBox bug related to sendfile that can lead to
    # corrupted files, if not turned-off
    # sendfile off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

       location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html/storage/web;
    }
}

## MISC ##
### WWW Redirect ###

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.armenianpartners.com www.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;
    return       301 https://armenianpartners.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.backend.armenianpartners.com www.backend.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;
    return       301 https://backend.armenianpartners.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.storage.armenianpartners.com www.storage.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;
    return       301 https://storage.armenianpartners.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.social.armenianpartners.com www.social.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;
    return       301 https://social.armenianpartners.com$request_uri;
}


## MISC ##
### OTHER sub-domains redirect ###
### NOT WORKING FOR HTTPS AS BROWSER WARNS REGARDING CERTIFICATE AND AFTER CLICKING CONTINUE SERVER REDIRECTS TO MAIN DOMAIN
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  *.armenianpartners.com *.armpartners.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;
    return       301 https://armenianpartners.com;
}

My project:
Yii2 framework
/var/www/html

Frontend (armenianpartners.com) - /frontend/web
Backend (backend.armenianpartners.com) - /backend/web
Social (social.armenianpartners.com) - /humhub
Storage (storage.armenianpartners.com) - /storage/web

I have .well-known/acme-challenge in all those folders.
I set all permissions and owning.
I created info.txt file and uploaded an image to acme-challenge folders, but unfortunately I got 404 when trying to open in browser (e.g. https://armenianpartners.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/table.jpg)
